# How to define a function inside flask model and use it for a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mongoengine, python-class

Here is my piece of code to define a function inside flask model and I want to use the output of the function as the default value of a variable (created).

```
class Test(db.Document):
    def default_date(self):
        tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
        return datetime.datetime.now()


    name = db.StringField(default="Anonymous")
    created = db.DateTimeField(default=default_date())
```

I am unable to use the output of default_date in created. Its giving me this error

```
TypeError: indian_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have even tried this without self. I am unsure whether I should use static method or class method for this.

Comment: `self.default_date` - with `self.` and probably without `()` because with `()` it will run at once and it will assign result for function as default value at start and use the same value all time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it to confirm but it should be with `self.` and without `()`

```
created = db.DateTimeField(default=self.default_date)
```

If you run with `()` then it will run this function immediatelly at start and it will assign result from function at start and later code will use always the same value.